# ArangoDB versions on Mac

Tags: arangodb

The [ArangoDB installation instructions](https://docs.arangodb.com/Installing/MacOSX.html) for MacOS state that Homebrew is the preferred installation method, but brew is behind the DMG packages available [here](https://www.arangodb.com/download/).  The brew version, including the --HEAD version, is 2.8.7, but my freshly (brew installed) system is complaining and asking me to upgrade to 2.8.9, available as a DMG package.

Should I stop using brew and instead use the DMG version?

Answer (score 1):

The Brew version lags a bit behind, since there are ongoing discussions about ArangoDB 3.0 features:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/1965/commits

These will hopefully be closed and accepted within the next days, you will get fresh versions soon.

Btw, a good point in time to try out ArangoDB 3.0 RC2 while its hot: 
https://www.arangodb.com/download-preview/